# Slanted Double Integral Signs

Tags: symbols, packages

Ok so this is the first time I am answering my own question. I am doing this because I have (until recently) really struggled with this and could not - for love nor money - find a solution online.

I like the 'standard' integral signs (given by `\int`, and more importantly, the 'standard' double integral signs (given by `\iint` in LaTeX using the `amsmath` package. A long time ago, I was creating a document and used these signs (no problem so far). However, a few weeks pass and I suddenly realise that, without my knowledge, all of the double integral signs have changed from the standard ones, to the shorter straight ones:

[image]

I had no idea how to reverse the effects or how they came about in the first place.

As it turns out (which I found out only recently) the `wasysym` package is to 'blame'. Unfortunately, this is really quite a useful package as it turns out. So I had no solution and just accepted that my document will not look as nice as it should. Oh well.

More recently I had the same situation with a new document, but this time I knew a little more about LaTeX so I thought: "No! I am going to solve this problem if it takes me all night!". Well it didn't... it actually took me nearly no time at all.

I simply used the `\renewcommand` command, changing `\iint` to mean `\int\int`.

**My Question:** Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I have not encountered a problem with my solution as of yet, but I am aware it is a bit of a cheat's way out.